# Sharing a directory from the VM to the host

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I use `config.vm.synced_folder` to sync folders from the host to the VM, but I'd like to sync it in the other direction. Is this possible using vagrant/virtualbox?

Comment: Once you create a `Synced` folder, it works both ways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Vagrant uses VirtualBox's `vboxsf` to sync folders between host and guest.

It is two way, so if you make changes to the files in `/vagrant_data` in the guest, it changes the corresponding files in the host's directory. You don't need to do it again the other way around.

Other options to sync files:

1. rsync
2. sshfs
3. NFS

See more => [Synced Folders](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to create a shared folder for Vagrant where files are being added from the guest machine and should show up in the host machine?

If that's the case, *you're still going to have to create the host folder*. I'm afraid Vagrant won't create the directory for you from a `config.vm.synced_folder` line in your Vagrantfile, but it will work fantastically once the host directory exists.

Comment: I think actually that vagrant will create the host folder if you use create: true as an option.

Comment: create option will also empty the directory in the guest machine